# When (if at all) did "visit with" fall out of fashion?

Tags: american-english, archaicisms

When consuming media (films, books, etc.) set in historic eras, one often hears the phrase "visit with." For instance, in *There Will Be Blood* (set across the period 1898 - 1930), Daniel Plainview tells a crowd of people that "I'm pretty easy to find and you just come and visit with me."

However, it's my impression that that phrase is not heard very often nowadays, with most preferring to use "visit" instead. I have two questions:

1. Are my suspicions correct that "visit with" is now archaic?
2. When did that change begin to occur?

Comment: _visit_ can also mean _chat/converse_. It is used intransitively in your example.

Comment: I am referring to the use of both "visit" and "visit with" in the sense of "go to see and spend time with (someone) socially."

Comment: Are you interested in a particular dialect/regional English? It seems to me that "visit with" is more American than British, at least at present. If you are, please add the relevant tag.

Comment: [These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visited+them%2Cvisited+with+them&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) hint that 'visited them' has always been the preferred version, even in the US, but that the prepositioned variant is actually becoming **more** frequent than it was.

Comment: See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446445/ive-been-visiting-with-a-friend/450750#450750).  (I don't find _visit with_ idiomatic, but apparently Americans do.)

Comment: @KateBunting: See my comment under my answer. Very few Americans (and virtually ***no***  Brits) find ***with*** idiomatic here, but I'm quite taken with the idea that a few (primarily, *rural*) Americans conflated ***visit with / stay with*** because visiting friends is/was a more substantial undertaking in a bigger country.

Answer (score 2):

I think OP's "archaisms" tag is misleading. Preposition ***with*** between ***visit*** and its object [was *never* in common use...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visit%20with%20us%20soon%2Cvisit%20us%20soon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=5)

[image]

It's only my opinion, but I suspect the tiny increase in prevalence after WW2 reflects a general tendency for usages to change when millions of military conscripts find themselves interacting with a wide variety of regionally distinct speakers.

I'm guessing the uptick for *You must visit **with** us* came about because a few people lacked the linguistic confidence to stick with their existing (prepositionless) usage after interacting with others who made no syntactic distinction between ***visit with us*** and ***stay with us***.

Most likely the usage arose in relatively isolated "dialectal pockets" that originally had a higher proportion of non-native Anglophones (who understandably would tend to simplify the relevant syntax of constructions learned later in life). But "Standard / Mainstream English" reasserted itself within a generation.

---

Note that "historical fiction" (literature *and* movies) shouldn't be seen as a reliable indicator of language use in the past. Authors and directors are rarely concerned with accuracy - they just want to give us the *illusion* of hearing people from the past. Most of us would have little to no chance of understanding anything Chaucer himself actually said, but that doesn't stop us watching movies with "pseudo-Chaucerian" vocabulary, syntax, and diction.

Comment: It feels dialectal to me, and not my own, either.

Comment: I had a look in Google Books, but was unable to find a *single* relevant instance of ***visit with us*** before 1850. Which doesn't imply there are any in the decades *after* 1850 - I just didn't look for them.

Comment: I just thought of another factor which is very likely to be relevant. In ***rural communities*** (the stereotypical "dialectal pockets"), ***visiting*** friends and ***staying with*** friends would often have been ***synonymous*** - because of the distances involved, and slower forms of transport in the past. Totally different to the sophisticated urban context, where so many visits would be relatively short affairs (involving "afternoon tea", for example). That might be relevant to why ***with*** virtually ***never*** occurs in BrE text (shorter distances! :)

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps I am making a mistaken association between rural and archaic.

Comment: @user770884: I wouldn't necessarily say "mistaken". There's often a *very close* association between rural and archaic. Language change happens mostly in densely populated urban regions, so "the Shires" will always tend to be behind the times.